# Better not trust the gcc default inliner?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization, inline

I was doing some hand optimizing some of my code and got bitten by gcc somehow.

The original code when run through a test takes about 3.5 seconds to finish execution.

I was confused why my optimized version now needs about 4.3 seconds to finish the test?

I applied `__attribute__((always_inline))` to one of the local static functions that sticked out in the profiler and now it proudly runs within 2.9 seconds. Nice.

I've always trusted gcc to make the decision in function inlining, but apparently it doesn't seem really that perfect. I don't understand why gcc ended up with a very wrong decision whether or not to inline a file-scope static function with `-O3 -flto -fwhole-program`. Is the compiler really just doing a guestimate to the cost-benefits of inlining a function?

Comment: Of course it's using a heuristic. Deciding what the perfect action would be is in general impossible, just like solving the halting problem. And the right action could also depend on what kind of input your app receives, something the compiler does not know anything about... perhaps a profile guided optimization could do a better job, but whether gcc does anything that smart, I have no idea...

Comment: If you are not already doing this, you can also set the CPU architecture, e.g. with the flag `-march=native`. This enables more optimizations, e.g. possible vectorization. GCC also has a parallel STL implementation which bring a huge performance benefit. Also, for performance-critical code, I would consider using Intel icc.

Comment: So you have found *one* case where the compiler wasn't doing the right thing. Wanna bet on how many years it will take before you find the next one?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath:  Use `-fprofile-generate` / `-fprofile-use` to give the compiler the data it needs to decide which functions to inline, and which loops to unroll.  It also lays out branches so the common path has fewer taken branches, leading to less pressure on the branch predictors, and fewer bubbles in the instruction-fetch stream.

Comment: @PeterCordes: what I meant to say is that I know you can do this, but I'm not sure that it will fix this specific issue. Would love to hear some feedback from the OP.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I'm not 100% sure either, but I think the inliner does use profile data.  So I'm about 95% confident that it'll solve the OPs problems.

Comment: @PeterCordes I did. Just right now with `-fprofile-generate` and `-fprofile-use`, but I don't know why I get 20% slower code..

Comment: @xiver77: Did you feed the `profile-generate` binary a representative test-case?  If gcc has misleading profile data, it could make worse decisions when you compile with `profile-use`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I applied both options to the same set of code.

Comment: with `profile-generate` first and then switching that to `profile-use`, other things equal.

Comment: @xiver77: you have to *run* the program that you created with `-fprofile-generate`, to create the `.gcda` profile data that `-fprofile-use` reads.  If you run it on a special case (like `./a.out --help`), gcc will think most of your program is unlikely to ever run.  I have no idea what you did, since you didn't say.  Hopefully you didn't do something silly like that, but I have to ask since I'm surprised at the 20% perf regression.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think I used those flags correctly. I found a similar issue to mine in an old gcc bug report. http://gcc.1065356.n5.nabble.com/fprofile-generate-and-fprofile-use-td662436.html

Comment: @xiver77: so you're doing something like `rm *.gcda; gcc -O3 -march=native -fprofile-generate *.c && ./a.out <sample_input && gcc -O3 -march=native -fprofile-use *.c`?  Weird.  Well, if you have time, file a gcc bug report.  Test cases where optimizations backfire are useful for gcc devs to improve the behaviour.  I just had a thought: maybe `profile-use` is somehow incompatible with whole-program or LTO?  Is the perf regression the same as what you get without those?

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm currently writing a header-only version in C++ which should give only one compilation unit to the compiler. I'll test how well PGO works in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: To answer the ACTUAL question, yes, the compiler does indeed "guesstimate" - or as the technical term is, it uses "heuristics" - to determine the gain in speed vs. space that inlining a particular function will result in. Heuristics is defined as "a practical but not theoretically perfect solution". End Edit.

Without seeing the code it's hard to say what is going on in the compiler. You are doing the right thing to profile your code, try your hand-optimisations and profile again - if it's better, keep it!

It's not that unusual that compilers get it wrong from time to time. Humans are more clever at times - but I would generally trust the compiler to get it right. It could be that the function is called many times and rather large, and thus the compiler decides that "it's above the threshold for code-bloat vs. speed gain"? Or it could be that it just doesn't get the "how much better/worse is it to inline" computation right.

Remember that the compiler is meant to be generic, and what works for one case may make another case worse - so the compiler has to compromise and come up with some reasonable heuristics that doesn't give too bad results too often.

If you can run profile-guided optimisation, it may help the compiler make the right decision (as it will know how many iterations and how often a particular branch is taken)...

If you can share the code with the GCC compiler team, report it as a bug - they may ignore/reject it as "too special" or some such, but it's quite possible that this particular case is something "that got missed out".

I think it's fair to say that the compiler "gets it right more often than not", but it doesn't mean it ALWAYS gets it right. I recently looked at some generated code from Clang, and it a whole bunch of extra instructions to unroll the loop - but in the most typical case, the loop would be one iteration, and never more than 16. So the additional instructions to unroll the loop by a factor of 4 was completely wasted for the case of one, and fairly useless even for the longest possible loop. The natural loop "rolled" would just be about 3-4 instructions, so the saving was quite small even if the loop was a lot bigger - but of course, had it been a million iterations, it would probably have tripled the speed of that function.

Comment: Things outside your edit tag actually helped better!

Comment: @xiver77: Yes, it's just that SOMETIMES I get the response that "you didn't answer the actual question", so I thought I'd cover that one too ;)

Comment: Almost all of the problems you describe (esp. useless unrolling) are avoided with `-fprofile-generate` / `-fprofile-use`.  (gcc used to include `-funroll-loops` in `-O3`, like clang still does.  These days, gcc only enables `-funroll-loops` with `-fprofile-use` (or if you use the option directly, of course).)